# Не получается удаление пробелов preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь удалить пробелы с помощью preg_replace(), обычно это не вызывает трудностей, однако в этот раз я потерпел фиаско!

```
 $aaa = 'ГОСТ 34.201-89 пам парам пам пам';
 if (preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*\d+\.\d+-\d+~iu",$aaa,$matches)) {
   echo 'Для '.$matches[0][0].'<hr>';
   echo preg_replace('/s+/', '', $matches[0][0]);
 }
```

ОТВЕТ ОТ СЕРВЕРА:

`Для ГОСТ 34.201-89
 ГОСТ 34.201-89`

Помогите удалить пробел.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f81651110deab30a9d234059af387333f617caf2 - Какой пробел?

Comment: А какой из них?

Comment: Если у вас там что-то непонятное, смотрите сюда: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

Comment: `'/s+/'` = 1+  букв `s`, `'/\s+/'` = 1+ пробельных символов.

Comment: Пробел который после слова ГОСТ

Comment: Manitikyl, Нужно именно с preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам одного слеша не хватило в нужном месте.

```
 $aaa = 'ГОСТ 34.201-89 пам парам пам пам';
 if (preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*\d+\.\d+-\d+~iu",$aaa,$matches)) {
   echo 'Для '.$matches[0][0].'<hr>';
   echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $matches[0][0]);
 }
```

> [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3de97fe12266cb600a0cbc47508817485b7d9ac6)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace(
  '/(.*)\s+?([\d\.\-]*)\s+?(.*)/u',
  'ГОСТ$2',
  'ГОСТ 34.201-89 пам парам пам пам'
);
```